# android - error while parsing JSON response from server

Tags: android, json

I'll try be to brief, please ask if something is unclear. I'm getting a user's audio list from vk.com (a large social network in case someone doesn't know). The response looks like:

```
   {"response":[{
  "aid":"60830458","owner_id":"6492","artist":"Noname","title":"Bosco",
  "duration":"195","url":"http:\/\/cs40.vkontakte.ru\/u06492\/audio\/2ce49d2b88.mp3"},
  {"aid":"59317035","owner_id":"6492","artist":"Mestre Barrao","title":"Sinhazinha",
  "duration":"234","url":"http:\/\/cs510.vkontakte.ru\/u2082836\/audio\/
  d100f76cb84e.mp3"}]}
```

Usually it is much longer since a user can have hundreds or even thousands of tracks on his profile. Artist and title can also contain cyrillic letters, that's why I used UTF-8 in the Parser. I'm not really familiar with JSON, I'm trying to parse the response using the following:

```
 public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";


public JSONParser() {

}

public static JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {


    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }


    return jObj;

}
  }
```

But the app crashes with an IllegalArgumentException exception (Illegal character in scheme at index 0):

```
02-27 10:37:35.870: E/AndroidRuntime(21038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 10:37:35.870: E/AndroidRuntime(21038): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.vadim.android.vk_player/com.vadim.android.vk_player.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0: {"response":[{"aid":191819427,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"Buena Vista Social Club","title":"El Cuarto de Tula","duration":445,"url":"http:\/\/cs548.userapi.com\/u361189\/audios\/b8c6a3bdb0bb.mp3","lyrics_id":"1133390"},{"aid":191477921,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"Buena Vista Social Club","title":"Hasta Siempre Comandante Che Guevara","duration":193,"url":"http:\/\/cs4515.userapi.com\/u7198823\/audios\/5fafa2136e16.mp3","lyrics_id":"2876258"},{"aid":190900891,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"Slade","title":"Oh la la in L.A.","duration":229,"url":"http:\/\/cs4962.userapi.com\/u9811745\/audios\/ed7445d38bef.mp3"},{"aid":188976833,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"PR-MEX","title":"У Билли Гейтса","duration":126,"url":"http:\/\/cs5002.userapi.com\/u4693819\/audios\/a1899ebb7716.mp3","lyrics_id":"5201762"},{"aid":186998450,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"The Best Latino Dance","title":"2Sweet-Bomba Latina","duration":213,"url":"http:\/\/cs4341.userapi.com\/u49441496\/audios\/788cd8243842.mp3"},{"aid":186486990,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"001 Track No05 Latin music 9","title":"001 Track No05 Latin music 9","duration":226,"url":"http:\/\/cs4341.userapi.com\/u25293142\/audios\/277e46d451d4.mp3"},{"aid":185813300,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"Латино ?? ","title":" Самбо","duration":190,"url":"http:\/\/cs4206.userapi.com\/u2183525\/audios\/678fe97a8700.mp3","lyrics_id":"4944025"},{"aid":185805191,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"Дженифер Лопес","title":"Латино","duration":212,"url":"http:\/\/cs4220.userapi.com\/u33799853\/audios\/685f4bc7024d.mp3","lyrics_id":"3985793"},{"aid":185355131,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"Latino","title":"Afa-Na-Na","duration":174,"url":"http:\/\/cs548.userapi.com\/u406078\/audios\/5e771c6958c4.mp3","lyrics_id":"8840070"},{"aid":185167860,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"Batuka-Latino_StepMIX(137bpm)","title":"demo","duration":232,"url":"http:\/\/cs4863.userapi.com\/u43189860\/audios\/b6a08490146a.mp3","lyrics_id":"10200160"},{"aid":185143167,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"Pr, Mex","title":"Ставил Windows программист","duration":130,"url":"http:\/\/cs4246.userapi.com\/u3476823\/audios\/75161ed38448.mp3","lyrics_id":"2012814"},{"aid":185141056,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"Antony Melnyk, Sergiy Tykhanskyy ","title":"Debugging Song","duration":234,"url":"http:\/\/cs6126.userapi.com\/u42350435\/audios\/f83f20d8d754.mp3","lyrics_id":"36053942"},{"aid":185141033,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"админ","title":"чистый дос","duration":173,"url":"http:\/\/cs4429.userapi.com\/u9853602\/audios\/2b77464f9193.mp3"},{"aid":184547392,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"Geri Halliwell","title":"Mi chico latino (samba)","duration":194,"url":"http:\/\/cs5057.userapi.com\/u8186180\/audios\/67119f2af914.mp3"},{"aid":184022338,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"Elena Paparizou","title":"My number one","duration":176,"url":"http:\/\/cs1092.userapi.com\/u830723\/audios\/25552d1f7e40.mp3","lyrics_id":"6640643"},{"aid":183519519,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"Latino - Samba - Elena Paparizou","title":"Gigolo","duration":203,"url":"http:\/\/cs4405.userapi.com\/u3609345\/audios\/5255ecdda950.mp3","lyrics_id":"7216473"},{"aid":183219402,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"David Bisbal ","title":" Llorare las penas (самба)","duration":260,"url":"http:\/\/cs5003.userapi.com\/u32245826\/audios\/fe718c40aed1.mp3"},{"aid":183110662,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"Juanes","title":"La soledad","duration":193,"url":"http:\/\/cs4615.userapi.com\/u400878\/audios\/40abd9dcb4f5.mp3","lyrics_id":"7753114"},{"aid":180455728,"owner_id":13590837,"artist":"Guns N' Roses","title":"Sweet Child O' Mine","duration":356,"url":"http:\/\/cs5125.userapi.com\/u1412326\/audios\/1fc190388445.mp3","lyrics_id":"5582681"},{"aid":180317426,"owner_id":1359083
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and what would be the correct way to parse the response of given format? There are a lot of apps using the same API so the JSON is correct.. No clue what's wrong here

Comment: your json is not valid.

Comment: thanks but like I mentioned there are a lot of apps using the same and it works. The vk support team also said the JSON is correct and I have to look for problems on my side

Comment: As I can see the problem is in the url's, after changing them to some other string it's parsing the json as it should be.

Comment: remove the image and post the logcat content as text

Comment: I checked it with JSONLint, seems the problem is really in the urls, but other vk developers say that JS and php JSON parsers remove the slashes automatically.. I thing I have to do this manually. Any idea how?

Comment: `myResponse = myResponse.replace("\","");`

Answer (score 0):

Illegal Argument Exception comes in JSON case while reading it. So invalid json because of those urls. Also for next communication, place the logcat as the text pls.

Comment: pasted it as text. Also tried  json = sb.toString();
            for(int i=0; i<json.length();i++){
             json = json.replace("\"", "");
            }
same error remains

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to display the JSON response in JSONlint.com without this url part of :
"url": "http:\/\/cs510.vkontakte.ru\/u2082836\/audio\/
  d100f76cb84e.mp3"

You will find, the response will be validated properly.

I think there is some space characters present in the url part (between audio\/ and d100f76cb84e.mp3) which is coming from response:
"url": "http:\/\/cs510.vkontakte.ru\/u2082836\/audio\/
  d100f76cb84e.mp3"
```